# select data based on a date column

Tags: oracle

I was trying to select some data  from my table using the following query:

`select * from table1 where column1 = to_date('14-05-14','yy-mm-dd');`

Where the column data type is `DATE`. I observed that,  the above query won't return anything unless we modified it as,

`select * from table1 where trunc(column1) = to_date('14-05-14','yy-mm-dd');`

even though there are records available.

I checked the documentation for `TRUNC`.Can anyone please explain why this happens?

**UPDATE**

As per the valuable comments I think some `time` values may also associated with the DATE. But I cannot view/edit that `time`. How can I ensure there are `time` values associated.

[image]

Comment: How about giving a SQL fiddle of your example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4

Comment: Alter your session with, `ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';` and see the results.

Comment: Ok. So the column with `DATE` data type by default hold the `TIME` value also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `TO_DATE` and `TRUNC` are different. See the below example.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
-------------------
28/05/2014 16:03:25

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)
-------------------
28/05/2014 00:00:00
```

In Your first query `to_date('14-05-14','yy-mm-dd')` is comparing with the date field `column1` in your table which has time values also. Whereas in Your 2nd query You are truncating the time part from table data and from Your query, that's why it's matching.

Answer (score 2):

The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the month, the day, the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after midnight).

TRUNC function will truncate the date to the day value, so that any hours, minutes, or seconds will be truncated off.

For more info please look at these below links

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php